# Application Of De Moivre & Euler's Formulae

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Can anyone show me how I can prove that $\sin x \cos (3x) = \frac{1}{4} \sin (7x) - \frac{1}{4}\sin (5x) + \frac{1}{2}\sin x$?
I tried using Euler's formulae
$$\sin x= \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$ 
and
$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
but the simplification didn't help at all.
PS: Simplify starting from the left.

Comment: It really is just a matter of substituting & multiplying.

Comment: OK thanks i'll retry

Comment: are you sure that is true?

Comment: I am not. ${}{}$

Comment: By the way how do i get rid of the i at the denominator without including i at the numerator

Comment: Let $x={ \pi \over 3}$ to show that they are not equal. My first comment was just wrong.

Comment: Yeah it was instead cos^3x thanks everyone

Answer (score 4):

It should be $\sin { x } \cos ^{ 2 }{ 3x } $

$$\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \sin { 7x } -\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \sin { 5x } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \sin { x } =\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \left( \sin { 7x } -\sin { 5x } +2\sin { x }  \right) =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \left( 2\sin { \frac { 7x-5x }{ 2 } \cos { \frac { 7x+5x }{ 2 }  }  } +2\sin { x }  \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \sin { x } \left( \cos { 6x } +1 \right)  \right) =\\ =\frac { \sin { x }  }{ 2 } \left( 2\cos ^{ 2 }{ 3x }  \right) =\sin { x } \cos ^{ 2 }{ 3x } \\ $$

Comment: Thanks for the correction and also the question required me to start from the left any idea?

Comment: @arsenestein You can always perform each of the steps this answer has done, in reverse.

Comment: Alright the mistake was the question I retried Euler's formulae and it worked fine thanks @haqnatural

Comment: you are welcome)

Comment: I wish to ask a question that hasn't anything to do with mathematics but with a maths exam is there any stackexchange site for such?

Comment: @arsenestein,unfortunately I haven't got any information

Answer (score 0):

Using $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1,$

$$4\sin x\cos^23x=2\sin x(2\cos^23x)=2\sin x(1+\cos6x)=\cdots$$

Now using [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html),  $$2\sin x\cos6x=\sin(x+6x)-\sin(6x-x)$$